# Book references (using some programming language) on Levy process estimation

Tags: r, python, estimation, references, stochastic-processes

Perhaps this type of question is not very suitable for this forum, but I'll try to make my question a little useful.

I'm studying stochastic processes, more precisely, Levy processes. A Levy process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is characterized by its characteristic function given by:
$$\log \varphi_{X_t}(u)= t\left(ib'u+ \frac{u'a u}{2} + \int_{\mathbb R^d - \{0\}} \left[ e^{i u'x} - 1 - i u'x \mathbf{1}_{(|x|\leq 1)}
 \right] \nu(dx)\right)$$
More precisely, the whole process is characterized by the triple $(a,b, \nu)$.

A good but extremely technical book is [Lévy Processes and Stochastic Calculus](https://www.cambridge.org/us/universitypress/subjects/statistics-probability/probability-theory-and-stochastic-processes/levy-processes-and-stochastic-calculus-2nd-edition). However, I am interested in estimating the triple $(a,b, \nu)$. Note that the drift $b\in\mathbb R^d$ and the matrix $a$ are finite dimensional parameters and, consequently, could be estimated with parametric techniques. On the other hand, the Levy measure $\nu$ might require non-parametric techniques.

So I'm looking for bibliographical references that help me in the computational part and implementation of the estimation of $(a,b, \nu)$.

The first chapter of book [Lévy Matters IV](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-12373-8) looks like a good book to me, but it's the only decent reference I've found. Also, maybe it's not as suitable for someone who doesn't have a lot of experience in the subject. So I would like to have suggestions for books with a more practical approach and, perhaps, using some language (R, python or some other).

Can you help me?

Comment: If you search *modeling levy process*, a wealth of research papers will appear.